# Nodejs app stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have application where i must load a lot of data from database.

A lot of objects in database has child objects. 
And i works with a lot of async loops.

```
async.eachSeries(....., function (item, cb) {
     ....
});
```

It's works fine, i have around 1000 objects in processing each second.

This functional works in background.
Sometimes my app just stuck and http server not response.

I think maybe i need to add something like delay to background data processing to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure if we'll be able to provide much help without more information and more code.

Comment: I needed to add setImmediate, looks like just stack overflow without exception

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem caused by doing jobs in series and when `job1` is not done, `job2` won't start and your app will stuck here. try doing you time consuming jobs in parallel way instead.